# I do not get Keycloak working in docker behind Traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, proxy, keycloak, traefik

I have a domain example.org.

I have docker running there with Traefik as proxy.
Now I want to setup Keycloak. I want to access Keycloak on auth.example.org.
This is my config (docker-compose):

```yaml
    keycloak:
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak
        restart: always
        command: start
        environment:
            KC_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: true
            KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
            KC_HOSTNAME: auth.example.org
            KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 443
            KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true
            KC_DB: postgres
            KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak?ssl=allow
            KC_DB_USERNAME: root
            KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
            KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
            KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: password
        labels:
            - "traefik.http.routers.cloud-network-keycloak.rule=Host(`auth.example.org`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.cloud-network-keycloak.entrypoints=websecure"
            - "traefik.http.routers.cloud-network-keycloak.tls.certresolver=letsencryptresolver"
            - "traefik.http.routers.cloud-network-keycloak.tls=true"
            - "traefik.http.services.cloud-network-keycloak.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
        depends_on:
            postgres:
                condition: service_healthy
        networks:
            - internal
            - traefik
```

However, loading the Keycloak admin console on `https://auth.example.org/admin/master/console/` throws an error in the browser:

URL: https://auth.example.org/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html/init?client_id=security-admin-console&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fauth.example.org
Status: 403

I have no clue ... how to resolve this?

Comment: You should be getting errors from `docker-compose` when you try to bring up that file: you're trying to set environment variables -- which can only be strings -- to boolean values (e.g., `KC_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: true`). That should be `KC_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"` (note the quotes).

Comment: Can you update your question to include a complete `docker-compose.yaml` that reproduces the problem? I tried to reproduce your configuration [here](https://gist.github.com/larsks/7bdc567be4fa2d66c8a37d1b022da4d3) and it seems to work without errors.

Comment: @larsks adding `KC_PROXY: edge` did the trick. But for the boolean values, I do not get any errors. However, I changed them to `"true"` syntax now. With it did the trick, I mean that I do not get any errors, however, I am sticking in an infinite loop of `Loading the admin console` loading animation now ... any ideas about this? I do not see any logs somewhere or any failures, it just loads and loads ...

Comment: That's a very common problem with keycloak. The only way I've found to solve it is to make sure that the hostname and port to which you're connecting match what keycloak expects (so e.g., in my example, I've set `KC_HOSTNAME_PORT` to `8443` because that's the port I've exposed from Traefik). See also https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/11083 which seems to have some discussion about this issue.

Comment: @larsks your sample docker-compose.yml works well, but I want to use port 443 directly, not 8443, then yours also hangs in infinite `loading the admin console` loop ... how to resolve this? see sample here https://bpa.st/3XWQ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get Keycloak responding properly on port 443, I need to remove the `KC_HOSTNAME_PORT` configuration, leaving me with:

```
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: docker.io/traefik
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.web-secure.address=:443
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak
    restart: always
    command: start
    environment:
      KC_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: "false"
      KC_HOSTNAME: auth.example.com
      KC_PROXY: edge
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: "true"
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/$POSTGRES_DB?ssl=allow
      KC_DB_USERNAME: $POSTGRES_USER
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: $POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: password
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.cloud-network-keycloak.rule=Host(`auth.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cloud-network-keycloak.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.cloud-network-keycloak.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"

  postgres:
    image: docker.io/postgres:14
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: $POSTGRES_USER
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      POSTGRES_DB: $POSTGRES_DB
```

This works for me without errors when I connect to it as
https://auth.example.com. If I re-introduce the `KC_HOSTNAME_PORT`
setting, I get the same "infinite spinning wheel" that you reported in
your question.

Comment: You won't have access to `auth.example.com` unless you've appropriately configured your local `hosts` file or otherwise arranged for name lookups to work. If you continue to have difficulty, you may want to open a new question.

Comment: Thank you! That worked on my localhost (I change to auth.example.localhost).

Comment: Glad it helped! This isn't a discussion forum, so the best way to ask "a followup question" is to post a new question on the site. Comments aren't really suitable for answering most questions (for example, it's not possible to format things like code or configuration in a useful fashion).

Comment: Just lifesaver. Just remove the `--host-name=<port>` and it works