# Keycloak in Docker with proxy such as nginx using non-standard ports

Tags: docker, nginx, keycloak, traefik

This is sort of a follow up question to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73259860/i-do-not-get-keycloak-working-in-docker-behind-traefik).

Originally, I tried to get Keycloak to work in Docker and needed TLS, so I used nginx with docker compose. But I got an infinite spinner like people in the question, which I found via Google when trying to solve my problem. So I read in answers that people in the question said not to `KC_HOSTNAME_PORT`. So I tried this and indeed, it worked with port 443.

That is fine and good, but I want to get Keycloak to work in my setup with different ports such as 8443. Can someone explain how to do this based on the setup offered in the original question I referred to? Or post a complete example with a docker-compose.yml of how to do it with nginx or traefik?

EDIT: If it helps, here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.2
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: 'false'
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: 'true'
      KC_PROXY: 'edge'
      # more
      KC_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      KC_HOSTNAME: kvm1.home
      #KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 4443
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command:
      - start-dev
      - "--proxy=edge"
      - "--hostname-strict-https=false"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.1
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./templates:/etc/nginx/templates
    ports:
      #- "8000:80"
      #- "4443:443"
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - NGINX_HOST=localhost
      - NGINX_PORT=80
    volumes:
      - ./ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
      - ./sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:rw
```

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name kvm1.home;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://kvm1.home:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

If I used the uncommented `KC_HOSTNAME_PORT` and the uncommented different ports in nginx.environment, I get the infinite spinner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want keycloak to expose keycloak on a different port, you need to make two changes:

- Change the port on which you're publishing `web-secure` endpoint from Traefik
- Set `KC_HOSTNAME_PORT` to match the new port

So that gets us:

```
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: docker.io/traefik
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.web-secure.address=:443
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"
      - "80:80"
      - "8443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak
    restart: always
    command: start
    environment:
      KC_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: "false"
      KC_HOSTNAME: auth.example.com
      KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 8443
      KC_PROXY: edge
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: "true"
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/$POSTGRES_DB?ssl=allow
      KC_DB_USERNAME: $POSTGRES_USER
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: $POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: password
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.cloud-network-keycloak.rule=Host(`auth.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cloud-network-keycloak.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.cloud-network-keycloak.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"

  postgres:
    image: docker.io/postgres:14
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: $POSTGRES_USER
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      POSTGRES_DB: $POSTGRES_DB
```

With this configuration, and an appropriate entry in my local `/etc/hosts`, file, I can access keycloak at `https://auth.example.com:8443`.

Comment: It's interesting to see that you answer, since you seem to be the original reply to the question I posted, where you said:
"If I re-introduce the KC_HOSTNAME_PORT setting, I get the same "infinite spinning wheel" that you reported in your question"

I will try to see if I can get it to work, but I used nginx and I got the infinite spinner when I used `KC_HOSTNAME_PORT`. What is different now that it did not work in your original reply. To me the solution for traefik looks like the solution I used in nginx and got the infinite spinner. Will try to experiment with it later.

Comment: I added my docker compose file with nginx.

Comment: Another observation: If I use my working configuration with port 443, if I add it to `KC_HOSTNAME_PORT` explicitly, it stops working and I get the spinner, even though the ports are the same.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for: the configuration I've presented here works for me and seems to do what you were asking. If this configuration isn't working as expected for you I would be happy to take a closer look, but I'm not going to re-implement it using an nginx ingress; that wasn't a requirement in your original question and it wasn't the configuration presented in the question to which you linked.

Comment: I'll try the solution with traefik and see if it works for me. If it does, I still would not understand why it does since in my mind my nginx attempt should be equivalent. I also wonder why in the linked question it was said that using `KC_HOSTNAME_PORT` breaks everything, yet here it should work now. Essentially I do not yet see the difference. Also, I should have probably asked for nginx, but my point mainly is that I do not understand the why, I just observe that `KC_HOSTNAME_PORT` breaks everything, even if I just use the same port. I'll try it out.

Comment: I could reproduce it on my end that it works. I will still try with my nginx config to see if I can get it working and then see if I can figure out the "why". Otherwise, you are right that I did not say that I "require" nginx to work and I should mark your solution as correct. I don't know if I should then post a new question as to why it works or if someone can help me with nginx to help my with my understanding.